# Counting white-spaces in a String in java

Tags: java

I have written a program which takes a `String` as user input and displays the count of letters, digits and `white-spaces`. I wrote the code using the `Tokenizer`-class, and it counts the letters and digits, but it leaves out the `white-spaces`. Any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class line {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter anything you want.");
    String text;
    int let = 0;
    int dig = 0;
    int space= 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    text = sc.next();
    char[]arr=text.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(arr[i])) {
            dig++;
        } else if (Character.isLetter(arr[i])) { 
            let++;
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(arr[i])) {
            space++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of Letters : "+let);
    System.out.println("Number of Digits : "+dig);
    System.out.println("Number of Whitespaces : "+space);
  }          
}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of Scanner and next(). What is a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `text = sc.next();` use `text = sc.nextLine();`

Comment: I think this might discard line breaks. But perhaps the OP doesn't want those in the total.

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` by default breaks the input into tokens, using *whitespace* as the delimiter!

Simply put, it gobbles up all the whitespace!

You can change the delimiter to something else using `sc.useDelimiter(/*ToDo - suitable character here - a semicolon perhaps*/)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have got problem in

```
sc.next();
```

except it, use

```
sc.nextLine();
```

it should work.

Comment: thanks! it works! can u please explain the difference between next() and nextLine(). i thought both of them for manipulating strings.

Comment: Using next() will return what comes before a space whereas nextLine() return the rest of the current line excluding line separator at the end.

Comment: yes, but next() gives you a next token in your string, by default it will be whitespace, so it will return you a word, until whitespace. nextLine() returns whole string you wrote down.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Line {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String s;
  System.out.println("Enter anything you want.");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  s = br.readLine();
  int length = s.length();
  int letters = 0;
  int numbers = 0;
  int spaces = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   char ch;
   ch = s.charAt(i);
   if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
    letters++;
   } else {
    if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
     numbers++;
    } else {
     if (Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
      spaces++;
     } else
      continue;
    }
   }
  }
  System.out.println("Number of letters::" + letters);
  System.out.println("Number of digits::" + numbers);
  System.out.println("Number of white spaces:::" + spaces);
 }
}
```