# want to find in which all index the 'space' comes in a given string

Tags: java

```
    String str;
    System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    str=s.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Space is at index ="str.indexOf(' '));  
     }
```

If I enter the string = "a b c d"
Then I want to print space is at index 1,3,5.
But the o/p is printing only 1 till the end of string lenght.

Comment: Have a think about how you can use `i` in your loop. Currently you're not using it at all.

Comment: why it is not using, pls try it in ur console .. it will loop until the string length and exit..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting white-spaces in a String in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602690/counting-white-spaces-in-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @ABAJAVa this code won't even compile.

Comment: Just call `indexOf(...)` until it returns -1 and pass the start index as well, i.e. you start at 0 for the first match and after the index of the first match for the second match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the javadoc of `indexOf(int ch)` method.

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified character.

As you can see, you are just keeping printing the first occurrence of **space** in given string.

Try code below:

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str;
        System.out.println("Enter the String: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        str=s.nextLine();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i) == ' '){
                System.out.println("Space is at index =" + i ); 
                count++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The total number of space is: " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefect and simple.. :-)

Comment: in the same code I am trying to print total number of space using  'int count' and incrementing it after "System.out.println("Space is at index =" + i ); "            But it is incrementing total length of the string..

Comment: @ABAJAVa See the edit for your requirement. Meanwhile, you'd better provide your code for us to check what you have done incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
    if(str.charAt(i) == ' ')
        System.out.println("Space is at index ="+i);  
}
```

`String#indexOf` just gives you the index of first appearance of given char.

Comment: it is printing total string length not the space as i is traversing till the end of string length

Comment: @ABAJAVa not it isn't, it'll print the index if the character at that index is a space.

Comment: it will work if we just add {  after If to loop it else it is thinking to print only total index..

Comment: @ABAJAVa I think you don't know that you can omit `{` `}` for single statements.

Comment: Ok, I agree i am new to programming. I got the required output

Comment: @ABAJAVa just as a side note: there are people (like myself) who prefer braces ( { and } ) even for single-statement blocks to prevent bugs that occur due to low attention and misreading (e.g. if someone adds a statement at the beginning and doesn't realize the braces would be needed now) - like they had in iOS a couple of months ago. So while you don't need braces for single-statement blocks you might want to get/stay used to using them anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

Just call `indexOf()` with a start index until you get -1 (which means not found). Note that the start index is inclusive so you'll need to add 1 to it.

```
String s = "a b c";
int index = -1;
while( (index = s.indexOf( ' ' , index + 1 )) != -1) {
  System.out.println( index );
}
```