# Why does a space or enter input not trigger the hasnextint validation check?

Tags: java, validation, command-line-interface

I have this code

```
boolean dataValidation = false;
System.out.println("Please input the id of the car");
      do {
           if (input.hasNextInt()){
           id = input.nextInt();
           dataValidation = true;
      } else {
           System.out.println("Please give a valid id number");
           dataValidation = false;
           input.next();
        }
      } while (!dataValidation);
```

But if I enter a space or just hit enter, the CLI returns nothing? I don't understand because it is clearly not an Int right?

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35602842/13927534

Comment: @MissSkooter thanks for commenting, but i dont think so because a delimiter isn't an int

Comment: yes, but you are inputting `space` not `int` which is being read as nothing since it is a delimeter. (at least that's what I understood from your question), which results in nothing happening

Comment: oh i see, is that the same thing that is happening when the user just hits enter without inputting anything? 

so when its int vs. nothing, no operation is run because it can't make a comparison?

Comment: I believe so yeah, unless you change the delimiter yourself as shown in the answer I linked

Comment: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#L1477 is where your call ends up, and then it loops until user inputs something what's not a delimiter. So it simply doesn't return if you just give it whitespace.